# How to save game score in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to save the game score in local storage.
I have tried

```
localStorage.setItem("score", myScore);
```

and

```
var score = localStorage.getItem(myScore);
```

to save the game score but it doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong? What should I do?

```js
function updateGameArea() {
        var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
                return;
            } 
        }
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
            minHeight = 20;
            maxHeight = 200;
            height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
            minGap = 50;
            maxGap = 200;
            gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            myObstacles[i].x += -1;
            myObstacles[i].update();
        }
        myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
        myScore.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
    
    localStorage.setItem("score", myScore);
    var score = localStorage.getItem(myScore);
```

Comment: your getitem is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is `"score"` not `myScore`

```
localStorage.setItem("score", myScore);
let score = localStorage.getItem("score"); // <--- key is "score", not myScore
```